# Eigen and lazy evaluation

Tags: c++, eigen3

I'm using Eigen3 in my program for everything related to matrices. I know that Eigen uses lazy evaluations to optimise all calculations. I would like to know if such an operation is optimised in the sense of limited unnecessary computations:

```
D = (A*B*C)(0,0);
```

where A,B,C are matrices and D is scalar. In english, I just need one element of the matrix product.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all coefficient-wise operations, the answer is yes. However, matrix products are special because, for efficiency reasons, they are by default evaluated within temporaries. You can enforce lazy evaluation of a matrix product using `lazyProduct`:

```
double ABij = A.lazyProduct(B)(i,j);
```

For a "triple" product like `A*B*C` the situation is more tricky because the nested product will be evaluated anyway (to avoid multiple re-evaluations in the general case), therefore you have to limit it yourself, e.g.:

```
 A.lazyProduct(B*C.col(j))(i);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was searching for. As far as I can see, a generalisation two a product of N matrices is complicated, isn't it? (I do not need that, but just out of curiosity)